# Role of vetctor after applying sort function to a matrix in R

Tags: r

What's the role of vector `I`after applying sort to column of matrix `s`?

```
    n = 10
    I = c(2, 8)
    s = matrix(runif(n*20), nrow=20)
    M  = apply(s, 2, sort)[I,]
```

Could we write this code in another eaiser way?

Comment: What vector? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you see what the code does by running it?

Comment: I change the code. Now you can see the result. but I do not know how the vector effect on matrix.

Comment: Your edits are not clarifying the issues with your question. Perhaps you should read a basic [introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html). Noone can answer whether you can write this code in an easier way if you don't know what the code is doing (or should be doing). SO users are not mindreaders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A power of R is indexing vectors or arrays not by a single value, but by a vector. Suppose the following example:

```
foo = 5:10 # foo = 5 6 7 8 9 10
foo[3]     # 7
foo[1:3]   # 5 6 7
foo[-2]    # excluding the 2nd item -> 5 7 8 9 10
```

Now on arrays:

```
bar = data.frame(1:3, 4:6)
bar[,2]                    # The 2nd column: 4 5 6
bar[-1,]                   # Excluding the first row
bar[c(2,3),]               # Extracts the second and third rows
```

In your original example, `apply(s, 2, sort)` sorts every column of the matrix `s` (If you used `apply(s, 1, sort)` it would sort rows), and then `[I,]` restricts the result of previous command  only to the 2nd and 8th rows. So after this program you will have only the 2nd and 8th smallest item in each column of `s`.

Note that `I` can have different meaning in R. In your case it is only a variable name, it could be anything else. But `I(x)` is also a function in R. For more info you may use `?I`.

Comment: @mnel thanks for the nice edits